# Gradient of Matrix

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

On the lecture notes here: http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/ee/ee263/ee263.1082/lectures/ls.pdf

the derivation for least squares is as follows.

$x^\intercal A^\intercal Ax - 2 y^\intercal Ax + y^\intercal y $

set gradient w.r.t. to x to 0

$2A^\intercal Ax - 2A^\intercal y = 0$.

How did this step come about? Does gradient mean derivative here? And what are some good resources for learning matrix calculus (more than Wikipedia, I want to develop intuition)? Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking what the definition of "gradient" is?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I think I know what it means, but I'm not sure. I guess my question is partially answered here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/369694/matrix-calculus-in-least-square-method?rq=1. My biggest question is how I go about learning these techniques.

Comment: Learn multivariable calculus.

Comment: If you only **think** you know what a gradient is, then you should first to a course that covers gradients (which would be something like analysis 2)

Comment: Any recommended textbooks/resources?

Comment: Any introduction to  multivariable calculus should do. But I would recommend actually taking a course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The gradient is the generalisation of the first derivative for a function of multiple variables. It is a vector whose component in the $i$-th coordinate direction is the $i$-th partial derivative.

In one variable, if a differentiable function has an extreme value at some point then its derivative must be zero there.

In several variables, if the function has an extreme value at some point then all partial derivatives must be zero there, in other words, the gradient is the zero vector.